# Failed Process Debug Main Manifest

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am recent on stackoverflow and Android Studio

I want to create an Android Studio game by integrating advertisements

I built the empty project it works well but when I add the Google Ads Sdk I get an error

You will find my different files then at the end my error

Thank you to all of them who will take the time!

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.empty"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.empty">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">

          <activity android:name="com.example.empty.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
android.injected.testOnly=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

**Here is my mistake**

```
app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0] /Users/builder/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f93ad182bd025d24e66677d5c16678a1/animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable' used in: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0, com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0.
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0] /Users/builder/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/011aabe7030756336ad3827e66b682f3/versionedparcelable-1.1.0/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Package name 'androidx.versionedparcelable' used in: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0.
/Users/builder/clone/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved same issue with following commands

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```

Clean and run it will work.

Basically these above command according to Mac so if you are using Windows or Linux please change path accordingly.